# My first integral test, is it correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to test for convergence on

$\sum \limits_{n=3}^\infty \cfrac1{n(\log n)(\log(\log n))}$

Now I have just learnt the integral test off of a fellow stack exchange user(M. Vinay).

$\int_3^\infty \cfrac1{n(\log n)(\log(\log n))} dn$

So I let $u = log(n)$ and get $dn = n du$, hence

$\int_{\log(3)}^\infty \frac1{u \log(u)}$, let $t = \log(u)$ and get $du = u dt$

$\int_{\log(\log(3))}^\infty \frac1t dt = 0 - \log(\log(\log(3)))$

Is this right? Now since it clearly exists it is convergent.

Comment: Up to the result of the last integral, it's right. What is $\int_a^b \frac{dt}{t}$? and what, therefore, $\int_a^\infty \frac{dt}{t}$?

Comment: As $B\to\infty$, $\log(\log(\log B))\to\infty$, though with extreme reluctance.

Comment: Oh that zero is meant to be $\log( \infty)$ isn't it, woops I put it into the $\frac1t$

So it seems to diverge then

Comment: @AndréNicolas What criteria is required for divergence under the integral test? I only learnt off of M. Vinay the criteria for convergence was existence.


Also off topic question, if you don't mind, it says that you can only obtain $200$ rep a day in the users menu, but your page has $\gt 300$ on some days, how is this possible?

Comment: Let $f$ be a decreasing positive function. Then $\sum f(n)$ exists if and only if for some $a$ the integral $\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt$ exists. So roughly speaking it goes both ways.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see, thank you.